# $\frac{dx}{dp_1}$ where $x=(p_1+p_2)^n$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

in my maths problem I need to find:

$\frac{dx}{dp_1}$ where $x=(p_1+p_2)^n$

could someone help me to find the answer ? I've looked everywhere but I am lost I would need your help.. thank you very much !

Comment: Are $p_1$ and $p_2$ functions of some variable or just constants?

Comment: they are constants

Comment: Is $n$ also a constant? It would be strange to have $n$ as a constant, but possible. If $n$ is not a constant, then $x$ is a constant.

Comment: I presume $p_1$ is a variable itself, since you're taking a derivative with respect to it

Answer (score 0):

Use the chain rule and the power rule and you get $n(p_1+p_2)^{n-1}$.